# Kotlin + Java 9 modules: Module java.base cannot be found in the module graph

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, java-module

I'm having some issues on building a Kotlin project that uses Java 9 features. I know kotlin just allow Java 8 bytecode generation, but acording to [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html) it should support this functionality since Kotlin 1.2:

> The Kotlin standard library is now fully compatible with the Java 9
>   module system, which forbids split packages (multiple jar files
>   declaring classes in the same package).

Well, lets to my problem: I'm getting this when I try to execute gradle `build` task:

> 04:29:27: Executing task 'build'...
>
> > Task :compileKotlin FAILED e: Module java.base cannot be found in the module graph e: Module java.management cannot be found in the
> >     module graph
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
>
>   > Compilation error. See log for more details
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s 1 actionable task: 1 executed Compilation error.
>   See log for more details 04:29:28: Task execution finished 'build'.

I searched for that error on Google and found [this topic](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-support-for-java-9-module-system/2499) where a guy had the same problem, he said he fixed it by targeting a JDK greater than 8, but I'm already with JDK 11 as project SDK and `sourceCompatibility`.

I'll left some important parts of build.gradle and project structure here to you guys inspect it.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    ...

    repositories { ... }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:0.9.17"
    }
}

plugins {
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven'


group 'io.github.dogobot.core'
version '4.0.0'

...

sourceCompatibility = 1.11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { ... }
    maven { ... }
    maven {
        url 'http://maven.ej-technologies.com/repository'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

module-info.java

```
module io.github.dogobot.core {
    requires kotlin.stdlib;
    requires kotlin.reflect;
    requires kotlin.logging;

    requires java.management;

    requires BootingBits;
}
```

I can run the project with no problems on Intellij Idea, just get this error when executing on gradle.

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I changed my gradle jdk from JDK 8 to JDK 11 and now it works like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me too, but in Maven. Changed the target jdk from 1.8 to 11 and it worked.

Comment: In my case I double checked this for a new project I had just imported that had this error. Everything was set correctly. Restarting IntelliJ resolved the error.

Answer (score 25):

**File -> Invalidate caches -> select "Clear file system cache and Local history" -> Invalidate and Restart**

Solved it for me...

Answer (score 3):

If changing JDK version doesn't work try the Repair IDE option in IntelliJ

***File -> Repair IDE***